# Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding

Tags: x11-forwarding

I have an unfortunate problem when making ssh connections from Fedora 23 to Centos 7. The commands `ssh -X user@centos7` and `ssh -Y user@centos7` both print **Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.**

Googling shows to add the following lines to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host *
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ForwardAgend yes
    ForwardX11 yes
```

But this didn't make the warning message go away.

Comment: Perhaps it was only a typo in posting the question, but `ForwardAgent` rather than `ForwardAgend`.

Answer (score 24):

For me this issue was caused by my Fedora system not having an `~/.Xauthority` file.

I created one by executing the following commands on my Fedora system (Client machine):

```
xauth add :0 . `mcookie`
```

Comment: More straightforwardly: `xauth generate :0 .`

Comment: this does remove the warning, my system is `5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64`

Comment: I case it isn't obvious (I made this mistake) - you need to run this on the **client**.

Comment: A hand trace of file clientloop.c from openssh-portable shows that the message depends on the client only. ssh runs "xauth list 127.0.0.1:0.0" locally. clientloop.c prints the warning message if xauth returns no data or error. Creating .Xauthority, as HeatfanJohn mentions, clears the warning.

Comment: The first comment did not work: $xauth generate :0 .
xauth:  file /home/XXX/.Xauthority does not exist
xauth: (argv):1:  couldn't query Security extension on display ":0"                                    $xauth add :0 . `mcookie` works.

Answer (score 11):

## Letting Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 run `ssh -X`  to get a GUI environment on a remote server

- First

Install all of the following. On Windows, install an X server, e.g.`Xming`. On Ubuntu bash, use `sudo apt install` to install `ssh xauth xorg`.

```
sudo apt install ssh xauth xorg
```

- Second

Go to the folder contains `ssh_config` file, mine is `/etc/ssh`.

- Third

Edit `ssh_config` as administrator(USE `sudo`). Inside `ssh_config`, remove the hash `#` in the lines `ForwardAgent`, `ForwardX11`, `ForwardX11Trusted`, and set the corresponding arguments to `yes`.

```
# /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

- Fourth

In `ssh_config` file, remove the front hash `#` before `Port 22` and `Protocol 2`, and also append a new line at the end of the file to state the xauth file location, `XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth`, remember write your own path of xauth file.

```
# /etc/ssh/ssh_config

#   IdentifyFile ...
    Port 22
    Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   ...
#   ...
    ...
    ...
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

- Fifth

Now, since we are done editing the `ssh_config` file, save it when we leave the editor. Now go to folder `~` or `$HOME`, append `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` to your `.bashrc` file and save it.

```
# ~/.bashrc
...
...
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

- Last

We are almost done. Restart your bash shell, open your `Xming` program and use `ssh -X yourusername@yourhost`. Then enjoy the GUI environment.

```
ssh -X yourusername@yourhost
```

The problem is also in Ubuntu subsystem on Windows, and the link is at

https://gist.github.com/DestinyOne/f236f71b9cdecd349507dfe90ebae776

Comment: Hahahah this is literally what I am doing, thanks mate!

Comment: Do not forget `DISPLAY=localhost:0`. Putting `DISPLAY=:0` breaks Cygwin ssh + VnXsrv.

Comment: For WSL, although you will be able to have successful X11 forwarding, you will still get a myriad of annoying messages about having to fake xauth credentials and other anomalous messages. Put `alias sshx="export DISPLAY=localhost:0; ssh -X"` in your `~/.bash_aliases`, source the file in your `~/.bashrc` (do all of this instead of exporting the `DISPLAY` environmental variable directly to your `~/.bashrc`). Then, use tmux and use `sshx username@remote_host`. When you are done, close out or detach that tmux session and you won't get those annoying messages when you are just using WSL.

Answer (score 9):

See https://serverfault.com/a/859370/423488

You might have to add a line like this to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` of the client system:

```
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

But use the actual path to the `xauth` program on your client system (where your client system is the one you are running ssh from).  You can find the path to `xauth` with this command:

```
which xauth
```

Answer (score -2):

Pipe `stderr` to a subshell that filters out the message with this incantation:

```
ssh yourusername@yourhost commandToRun 2> >( sed '/Warning: No xauth data/d')
```

Nothing to install, nothing to configure, nothing can go wrong!

Comment: This answer has got a few downvotes, but in some cases, e.g. if the X server is started without '-auth', this is an expected warning even without forwarding X11.  In these cases, this is the correct answer.